# Adding new geoJSON polyline layer to mapbox styles using Android Studio

Tags: geojson, java, mapbox, android

I am trying to add new geoJson polyline layer to mapbox in Android Studio. It works fine if I am adding it using the default style of mapbox, but if I set my own styles, the line is not drawn anymore in my app. Could anyone tell me what could be wrong?

```
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

            // Create the LineString from the list of coordinates and then make a GeoJSON
            // FeatureCollection so we can add the line to our map as a layer.

           if ("city".equals(spinner2)) {
                mapboxMap.setStyleUrl("mapbox://styles/johan88/cj1fdzcoo00012spgu1lldduk");
            }
            else if ("beach".equals(spinner2)) {
               mapboxMap.setStyleUrl("mapbox://styles/johan88/cj3cuj7a800032rmqsrhir1av");
            }
            else if ("adventure".equals(spinner2)) {
                mapboxMap.setStyleUrl("mapbox://styles/johan88/cj37g9zzz00092rqp7c55ufxt");
                // Customize map with markers, polylines, etc.
            }

            LineString lineString = LineString.fromCoordinates(routeCoordinates);

            FeatureCollection featureCollection =
                    FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(new Feature[]{Feature.fromGeometry(lineString)});


            Source geoJsonSource = new GeoJsonSource("line-source", featureCollection);

            mapboxMap.addSource(geoJsonSource);

            LineLayer lineLayer = new LineLayer("linelayer", "line-source");

            // The layer properties for our line. This is where we make the line dotted, set the
            // color, etc.
            lineLayer.setProperties(
                    PropertyFactory.lineDasharray(new Float[]{0.01f, 2f}),
                    PropertyFactory.lineCap(Property.LINE_CAP_ROUND),
                    PropertyFactory.lineJoin(Property.LINE_JOIN_ROUND),
                    PropertyFactory.lineWidth(5f),
                    PropertyFactory.lineColor(Color.parseColor("#e55e5e"))
            );
            mapboxMap.addLayerBelow(lineLayer, "Water labels");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also not able to get Mapbox (5.5.0) to draw a LineLayer, until I built the FeatureCollection from a JSON string.

I was inspired to try this by this old bug report:
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/6240

Try using this function to build your FeatureCollection:

```
private static FeatureCollection getFeatureCollection(List<LatLng> positions) {
    StringBuilder jsonBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    jsonBuilder.append("{\"type\":\"FeatureCollection\",\"features\":[{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"LineString\",\"coordinates\":[");
    ListIterator<LatLng> listIterator = positions.listIterator();
    while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
        LatLng position = listIterator.next();
        jsonBuilder.append('[');
        jsonBuilder.append(position.longitude);
        jsonBuilder.append(',');
        jsonBuilder.append(position.latitude);
        jsonBuilder.append(']');
        if (listIterator.hasNext()) {
            jsonBuilder.append(',');
        }
    }
    jsonBuilder.append("]},\"properties\":{}}]}");
    return BaseFeatureCollection.fromJson(jsonBuilder.toString());
}
```